# Internet Explorer for SSL client authentication

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, server-side, keytool

I was trying to access the server with need client authentication set to 'Yes'.

Does the web browser have the capability to present the client certificate I  import the certificate to the server keystore 
and install the same in the web browser.

The SOAP UI tool does allows to configure the keystore and works well with the client authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Internet Explorer is capable of performing client-certificate authentication. It will rely on certificates in your "Personal" certificate store.

You may be interested in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/03/client-certificate-selection-prompt.aspx) and the "*Don't prompt for client certificate selection when only one certificate exists.*" option in "Internet Options" -> "Security" -> "Custom Level...".

Note that none of this has anything to do with "importing the [client] certificate to the server keystore". When the client sends its certificate, it is verified against the server's truststore. This is an operation performed during the handshake, and no certificate is imported in the server truststore. The truststore should already contain a suitable CA (configured in advance).